# In bash, how to retrieve string starting with a specific expression?

Tags: bash

Given this piece of file:

```
a=as/dsdf b=fdfsf c=vcv
c=15 b=1 a=azzzz))]ee
a=12 z=19 r=15
```

I want to retrieve only the parts starting with **a=**

so the output in this case would be:

```
a=as/dsdf
a=azzzz))]ee
a=12
```

I've dived into bash documentation but couldn't find anything easy, do you have any suggestion ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want everything starting with `a=` up to the next space.

It's not supported by all versions of grep but if you have the `-o` option this is easy:

```
grep -Eo 'a=[^ ]+' file
```

`-o` prints the matching part of the line. `-E` enables [**Extended** Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_04), which enables you to use `+` to mean *one or more* occurrences of the preceding *atom**. `[^ ]` means any character other than a space.

Otherwise, use sed to capture the part you're interested in:

```
sed -E 's/.*(a=[^ ]+).*/\1/' file
```

As a last resort, if your version of sed doesn't support extended regexes, this should work on any version:

```
sed 's/.*\(a=[^ ]\{1,\}\).*/\1/' file
```

As rightly pointed out in the comments (thanks), to avoid printing lines that don't match, you may also want to use `-n` to suppress output and add a `p` command to print lines that match:

```
sed -nE 's/.*(a=[^ ]+).*/\1/p' file
```

---

*atom** : A character class, a marked sub-expression or a single character.

Comment: You properly want to remove lines that doesn't contain `a=...`

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here is a pure `bash` solution that does not reply on an external program:

```
while read -a fields
do
    for (( i=0; i< ${#fields}; i++ ))
    do
        [[ ${fields[i]} == a=* ]] && echo ${fields[$i]}
    done
done < gash.txt
```

This assumes that the input file is `gash.txt`.

We `read` each line into an array called `fields`, using the default `IFS` split on whitespace to populate the array.  Then we iterate through the array looking for the glob construct `a=*` (not a regular expression), which means `a=` followed by zero or more of any character.

And here is an `awk` solution (called from `bash`):

```
awk -f - gash.txt << '_END_'
{ for (i=1; i <= NF; i++)
      if ($i ~ "^a=") print $i
}    
_END_
```

or if you prefer a one-liner:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i <= NF; i++) if ($i ~ "^a=") print $i }' gash.txt
```