# How to retrieve all code between two words in shell?

Tags: linux, algorithm, shell

I need your help.

I have a text file with many lines and for each line i want to extract a code.
This code is betwwen two pattern :

1) "quarantine"

2) ","

Exemple of my log.txt :

> George Thibault give two balls **quarantine: x27041992,** to someone
>
> Edward Thin give three PC'S **quarantine : m5405051993,** to Fed
>
> Tommy Dijoux give one shoe **quarantine : cD001252000,** to luc

Wanted result in new file :

> x27041992
>
> m5405051993
>
> cD001252000

Someone can help me please ?

Comment: Have a look at `sed`

Comment: I don't know if sed work in line level ?? and if it will return all code

Comment: `grep -oP 'x\d{8}' log.txt`, maybe?

Comment: hi @twalberg , manny time the code dont begin with x . the only things that don't change are the words "**qurantine:**" befoe and "**,**" after the code

Comment: @Oracleboy97420 `sed` comes with a man page that answers these questions. Or do you really want us to do your work?

Comment: @Henry if you dont want to help dont be rude please !

Comment: See if you can adapt [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36714646/2088135) (or look up one of the countless other similar examples).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
>output
while read line; do
    for word in $line; do
        if [[ $word == *","* ]]; then
            echo ${word::-1} >> output
        fi
    done
done < gr
```

Note: Using shell loop to process text file is not a good practice.
[read this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

Match the substring between quarantine and the first `,`, and replace everthing with the remembered string.
When you alse wont to delete a `:`, change this command.

```
sed 's/.*quarantine\([^,]*,.*/\1/' log.txt
```